# class for model choices

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

How can I use a class for choices of a model in Django?

Here is kind of what I want:

```
class ChoicesCls(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.OPTION_ONE = 'O1'
        self.OPTION_ONE_SHORT = 'Opt 1'
        self.OPTION_ONE_LONG = 'Option 1'
        self.OPTION_TWO = 'O2'
        self.OPTION_TWO_SHORT = 'Opt 2'
        self.OPTION_TWO_LONG = 'Option 2'

    def get_choices(self):
        return (
            (self.OPTION_ONE, self.OPTION_ONE_LONG),
            (self.OPTION_TWO, self.OPTION_TWO_LONG)
        )


class TestModel(models.Model):
    choices_obj = ChoicesCls()
    field = models.CharField(choices=choices_obj.get_choices)
```

The main reason I want something like this is so in another place I can do something like

```
option = "ONE"
getattr(TestModel.choices_obj, "OPTION_{}_SHORT".format(option))
```

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve. Your getattr() example doesn't work because you are trying to get instance attributes from a tuple, not from the original choices class. That said, Django doesn't care how you generate the choices tuple as long as it is properly formatted.

Comment: @MadWombat I am trying to `getattr` on the `ChoicesCls` not the tuple.

Comment: In the code you posted TestModel.choices is the result of the get_choices() method, not the ChoicesCls() instance.

Comment: That said, nothing prevents you from defining your own class and making it behave like a tuple of tuples Django expects.

Comment: I don't see where you are getting that, it is an instance of `ChoicesCls`. See `choices = ChoicesCls()`

Comment: Mad Wombat means the `TestModel.field.choices` is defined by the method (I think)

Comment: Your code says `field = models.CharField(choices=choices.get_choices)`. `choices.get_choices` is not the class or an instance, it is a method, so it doesn't work because you are passing a method reference where a tuple is expected. But neither `choices.get_choices` nor `choices.get_choices()` is an instance of `ChoicesCls`

Comment: If you look at the line above you will see the instance of `ChoicesCls` which is what I am point to in the `getattr`

Comment: @MadWombat - I'm pretty sure django can resolve a method when the choices are required for it, I think the problem is you have no guarrantee that `choices` will be initialized *before* the `field`

Comment: Anyway, as I said, you can define a class that behaves like the tuple Django expects. You need to define __iter__() and __getitem__() I think.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, was looking at the wrong code

Comment: I cleaned up the example to clear that up.

Comment: @Sayse I am pretty sure things are processed sequentially, so if you define your choices class before your model, your choices will get initialized before your field.

Comment: @Sayse, I believe MadWombat is correct. Things are processed sequentially when doing migrations. Which is where the model state is rendered.

Comment: Choices are not stored in the database so migrations have nothing to do with it.As I understand it, Class attributes are [stored in there own namespace as a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html), and obviously dictionaries aren't ordered.  (cc: @MadWombat)

Comment: @Sayse, yes you are correct they aren't directly stored. But if you change a choice in the choices and run `makemigrations` it will generate a new migrations files with the updated choices. This is used for rendering the model state. The point being is that when this happens it is all sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
class FakeChoices:
    def __init__(self):
        self.OPTION_ONE = 'O1'
        self.OPTION_ONE_SHORT = 'Opt 1'
        self.OPTION_ONE_LONG = 'Option 1'
        self.OPTION_TWO = 'O2'
        self.OPTION_TWO_SHORT = 'Opt 2'
        self.OPTION_TWO_LONG = 'Option 2'

    def __get_tuple(self):
        return (
            (self.OPTION_ONE, self.OPTION_ONE_LONG),
            (self.OPTION_TWO, self.OPTION_TWO_LONG)
        )

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__get_tuple()[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__get_tuple())

...

class TestModel(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(choices=FakeChoices())
```

As you might imagine you can put all sorts of crazy logic inside FakeChoices class. And you should be able to do

```
option = "ONE"
getattr(TestModel._meta.get_field('field').choices, "OPTION_{}_SHORT".format(option))
```

Comment: I edited my answer to incorporate your getattr() example

Comment: I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'Creator' object has no attribute 'choices'`

Comment: Looks like you cannot directly access fields from model class. One second, I will update the answer.

Comment: I will just instantiate another instance of the class where I need to do the getattr. will work fine :)

Comment: Well, no, since you need the actual field definition and not the field value. I just updated the getattr() code to access the choices properly

Comment: Since accessing the meta of the model is a bit messy and ugly, I chose to go with just instantiating an instance of the `FakeChoices` in the script that is using the `getattr` and then just pointing the `getattr` to that instance instead of the one on the model.

Comment: That works as well. It seems that accessing _meta for model specific information is blessed by django devs as the official way though
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/

Comment: But it is more readable to just do `self.choices = FakeChoices()` in the `init` of the `Command` class then just doing `getattr(self.choices, "OPTION_{}_SHORT".format(option))` when you need to get that value. Thanks for the answer, this is really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you're trying to initialize something outside of a class instance so you could do

```
field = models.CharField(choices=ChoicesCls().get_choices())
```

But that still isn't very usable (in my opinion)

I find it better to just import a tuple list from a module and use that as the choices, there isn't any need to generate a class for this.

This has the added benefit that it allows you to do the second thing you are trying to do since you define the options at module level also

```
OPTION_ONE_WITH_A_GOOD_NAME = '1'
OPTION_TWO_WITH_A_GOOD_NAME = '2'

MY_GOOD_NAME_CHOICES = [(OPTION_ONE_WITH_A_GOOD_NAME,OPTION_ONE_WITH_A_GOOD_NAME),
                        (OPTION_TWO_WITH_A_GOOD_NAME,OPTION_TWO_WITH_A_GOOD_NAME)]
```

Comment: Can I do `getattr` on a module? If so, you might be right and that would be better. But I need something more than just a plain old tuple because I need more info.

Comment: @electrometro - You don't need `getattr` at all, just import the option you're comparing with

Answer (score 0):

To extend [Mad Wombat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36066833/1529346), you could create a custom field:

```
class ChoicesCharField(CharField):
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, virtual_only=False):
        super().contribute_to_class(cls, name, virtual_only)

        def get_FOO_display_short(s):
            value = getattr(s, self.name)
            return self.choices.get_short_name(value)
        get_FOO_display_short.__name__ = 'get_{}_display_short'.format(self.name)
        get_FOO_display_short.short_description = self.verbose_name
        get_FOO_display_short.admin_order_field = self.name

        setattr(cls, get_FOO_display_short.__name__, get_FOO_display_short)
```

So that you can use `my_model_instance.get_field_display_short()`, as you would usually do with `my_model_instance.get_field_display()`.

Comment: Funny enough, I am actually already using a custom field for this particular field, but for something else. But I am really trying to shoot for readability and maintainability here so I am gonna go with the simple answer.

Comment: This does not prevent you from adding the `contribute_to_class` method to your custom field, or create a custom field that extends your custom field rather than `CharField`. :)

Comment: You are right there, but I feel if another dev wanted to find the functionality of how this all works looking in the field might not be the best place for it. Where as just instantiating another instance of the `FakeChoices` class where we need to `getattr` is much clearer.